# What is the general strategy for troubleshooting visual C++ redistributable install "errors"?

Tags: windows-8.1, c++, redistributable

I went to install Autodesk Inventor 2017 and got stuck without errors on "installing microsoft visual c++ redistributable 2012 x86 11.0.61030", so I tried to run the installer manually. It said it was already installed, so I tried to uninstall from the installer. It stalled at "initializing" without error. I cancelled out, tried uninstalling from "programs and features" - same deal. Tried to rebuild installer database with DISM, reported success but didn't help. Tried Microsoft "Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter", it didn't list as installed. The troubleshooter had an option to input a product code, so I did

```
get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name
```

in powershell and *none* of the redistributables showed up. How should I proceed?

Google indicates that the problem is popular but no consistent solution has presented itself. Ideas? In particular, are there any ideas of the underlying problem? Away in the dim recesses of my memory, I remember having an issue like this *years* ago, and the solution being to uninstall *all* the redistributables and install them in a specific order. Since I have about twelve of them, seems like a nuclear option.

EDIT:

Oh look, another thing that adesk never got around to fixing

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-remove-and-reinstall-Microsoft-Visual-C-Runtime-Libraries.html

I'd still love to know exactly what the hell is going on

Comment: All you have to do is remove the same version of the redistributable.  So if you have two versions of 2012, uninstall those, uninstalling the other versions (2010,2013,2015) makes no sense.

Comment: How do you mean, two versions? x86 and x64? Or, 2 numbered versions of the same package? If both are the case, should I uninstall all 4?

Comment: I mean `11.0.xxxxx`, `11.0.xxxxxx`, `11.0.61030`

Comment: Hm, I will see if I can do that, or if I get the same "error"